# Stop reading string when key is hit

Tags: java, android, string

If I have a string of garbage like

> this is a sentence that is stackoverflow's property.

How can I read the string until the apostrophe (or the key I want to set up) is hit so it would return

> this is a sentence that is stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to find the first index of the character, then return the whole string if it isn't found or the substring from the start of the string up to (but not including) the index of the character if it is.

```
int index = string.indexOf('\'');
return index == -1 ? string : string.substring(0, index);
```

Comment: Is there a way make an offset so that it won't look at the first 8 chars of the string for the apostrophe but if will still return the whole string? So strings that have a apostrophe in the first 8 chars are ignored while apostrophes outside of 8 chars will be recognized.

Comment: @Nick: I suggest taking a look at the methods of `String`. The overload `indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)` takes a character and an index to start looking for that character at. So `indexOf('\'', 8)` would do what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
String desiredString = myString.split("\\.")[0];
```

Comment: The issue with this is that it checks the entire string even if the character appears early in the string. It also compiles a regex `Pattern` and creates an unnecessary array.